# C data type confusion

Tags: c

When I enter large numbers like 3,000,000,000 (without commas), I don't get the right result. The number shown is not larger than 9 digits no matter how big a number I input.

The question is as follows:

> Perform the following calculation, where the system only accepts positive integers from `0` to `3x109` (i.e. `3,000,000,000`), and shows the results as a VDU output: `y = 3x2 - 2x + 6`.
>
> You do not need to check in your algorithm if the number is an integer or within the range. We will assume it is always entered correctly. However, you must attempt to code using the correct data type. Please check data types in the book for using positive integers that will be within the dened range

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned x=0, y=0;

    printf("Enter a positive number between 0 to 300000000\n");
    scanf("%u",&x);

    y=(3*x*x)-(2*x)+6;
    
    printf("\n\nThe value of y is %u",y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: "VDU output"... Quick OT question: can you check in what year your lesson book was printed?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format code for `scanf`/`printf`.  `%d` is a signed integer.  Use `%u` for unsigned integers.

What is happening is that `scanf` with a `%d` is reading the user input as a signed integer and will scan in a negative number.   `scanf` does not check the datatype of the variable you pass in so it does get stored in an unsigned variable - however it isn't stored as -10, since the variable is unsigned.  Instead it will be a very large positive number becuase of how negative numbers are stored ([Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

Correct input valiation takes some work, which is why your instructions say to ignore it.

Comment: how do i get a vdu output?one last question is there any particular square function(for x*x)

Comment: Even using %u will not correct that. The return value will be, most likely, out of range, since the negative number will be converted to a two's complement.

Comment: Ya i used %u but still the problem presists.is there any way to make it like always positive because from the book what i learned was unsigned makes negative inputs positive(correct me if im wrong--a total newbie)

Comment: @OchinOchin - you'd have to do input validation yourself.  You could read it in using `%d` and a signed variable and then check for negative.  You'd still have an issue if the user entered a string you would crash.   To handle that you'd have to read your input into a string and manually parse it.  Then you have to worry about entering a string that's too long.   Input validation takes some work - this seems to be something that you don't have to worry about on your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

x cannot take the value -10. As stated in your question, you do not need to check for the value, because *it is assumed to always be entered correctly*. By using -10, you defeat the assumption. Just use only positive numbers in your checks.

EDIT: In addition, by using `unsigned` you imply `unsigned int`. The maximum number can only fit to an int, if the c-int you use is a 32-bit int, not a 16-bit int.

EDIT2: In addition to you having to use %u in the scanf function, you also need to output using the format given to you. That is you need to *visualize* your calculation line on screen.

The information given should already be enough for you to figure out the answer. This is an assignment, and you are supposed to do something on your own, right?

Comment: for unsigned do i have to use %u in scanf?and how do i get a vdu output?one last question is there any particular square function(for x*x)

Comment: @Ochin Ochin There is the sqrt function in the math library, if you are allowed to use it. I am pretty sure you are expected to read using %u.

Answer (score 0):

because of value is bigger than the maxi. limit of integer data type so, if you enter value more than the range of integer than it will be roll over ,that's why you didn't got right value.
so for this if you want to avoid this problem than you have to use long long integer than you will get right value